# How to check Android Os Version?

Tags: android

I have an Android tablet and I want to know the OS version. I checked in Settings->About Device but there is no OS version present. It says,

```
Model Number:Generic
Firmware Version:1.6
Kernel Version:2.6 29-00236-g4f8dbbb-dirty
Build Number:WMT2.1_88
```

How would I know OS version from this?

Comment: This is a question for android.stackexchange.com, unless you want to find out programmatically. In any case, it says "1.6", that sounds like 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Generic Firmware Version:1.6

Looks like you are running a Donut.

Comment: Please Clarify one thing,does firmware version represents OS version?